# PowerShell script working directory (current location)

Tags: powershell, path, scripting, working-directory

When I launch a PowerShell script from any folder (e.g. `C:\Scripts`),
the 'current' PowerShell folder in the script
is always the User Profile Folder
(e.g. `c:\users\Joe` ; test with a script with only `Get-Location`)

But should be the folder from where the script was launched...

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**When PowerShell *directly* invokes a `*.ps1` script**, that script runs *in-process*, in the same runspace as the caller, and therefore **the script by default sees the *same* current location (working directory) as the caller**.

As an aside: Conversely, if a script *changes* the current location, the caller sees that too, after the script exits (see below for details).

**If you do *not* see this behavior, the implication is that *some* behind-the-scenes code is changing the current location.**

---

The only way I can realistically see this happen is in the following scenarios:

- If (a) your `$PROFILE` file contains a `Set-Location` / `Push-Location` command that explicitly switches to your home folder *or* (b) (as in your case, as we now know) if there is - broken - code in an auto-loading module that does that on (automatic) import<sup>[1]</sup> *and*:

  - You call PowerShell via its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) (`powershell.exe` for *Windows PowerShell*, `pwsh` for PowerShell *Core*) *without the `-NoProfile` switch*; e.g. `powershell -File someScript.ps1`
  - On Unix-like platforms, your script is implemented and called as an extension-less, executable shell script with a shebang line (that doesn't include `-NoProfile` - see below for details).
- If you run your script via one of the following commands / features:

  - Via `Start-Job` (in a child process) or `Start-ThreadJob` (in a new runspace), at least currently (PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.4)

    - Note: These two cmdlets don't behave exactly the same, which is problematic in and of itself, but the larger problem is that they don't simply inherit the *caller's* current location - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10673).
  - Via the PowerShell SDK, in a new runspace.

Other than that, I can only see *accidental* event-based code producing your symptom, such as the following - pointless - redefinition of the interactive prompt-string defining function, `prompt`, to make it quietly switch to the `$HOME` directory after every command:

```
# !! Obviously, do NOT do this.
function prompt { 
  # Print the usual prompt string.
  "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
  # Quietly return to $HOME
  Set-Location $HOME 
}
```

The rest of the answer discusses a related scenario that may be of interest.

---

#### Executing a PowerShell script with its own directory as the working directory (current location):

In PowerShell v3+, automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot` contains the full path of the directory in which the executing script is located.

**If you need your script to execute with its own directory as the working directory** (current location), use the following approach:

```
# Save the current location and switch to this script's directory.
# Note: This shouldn't fail; if it did, it would indicate a
#       serious system-wide problem.
$prevPwd = $PWD; Set-Location -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot

try {
 # Your script's body here.
 # ... 
 $PWD  # output the current location 
}
finally {
  # Restore the previous location.
  $prevPwd | Set-Location
}
```

Note:

- The reason for explicitly restoring the previous location (directory) is that **PowerShell runs scripts (`.ps1` files) *in-process***, so if a script changes the current location with **`Set-Location` or `Push-Location`**, it **takes effect *session-globally***; that is, the new location lingers even after the script exits.
- On **Unix-like platforms** (Linux, macOS), with PowerShell *Core*, you now have the option of creating (extension-less) executable shell **scripts with a [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/45375)**; such scripts **run in a *child process***, and there is therefore ***no* need to restore the previous location (directory)**.

  - Unfortunately, accessing information about the script's own invocation, including `$PSScriptRoot`, is *broken* in shebang-based scripts, as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.4, as discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4217).

---

<sup>[1] No module should ever change the session-global state on import (aside from importing its commands), but it is technically *possible*, namely if you place commands such as `Set-Location` in the top-level scope of a script module's `*.psm1` file or in the scripts that run in the caller's scope via the `ScriptsToProcess` module-manifest entry. Even binary cmdlets can execute code at import time, via the `System.Management.Automation.IModuleAssemblyInitializer` interface - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624757/45375).</sup>