How to limit exported commands from binary powershell module (*.dll file)?
I know I can limit exported commands from module that is imported like this:
Import-Module C:\...\MyModule or Import-Module C:\...\MyModule\MyModule.psd1
Then I can use CmdletsToExport in .psd1.
But, what if I import module from .dll?
Import-Module C:\...\MyModule.dll
How to limit exported commands (cmdlets)?
There are cmdlets in our .dll that should be "hidden" in default and we want to allow calls of them only if some environment variable has some value.
I was thinking that Powershell maybe uses reflection to get commands from .dll, so maybe there is some way to catch some "module initialized" event where I could somehow influence what cmdlets should be exported.

Why make them cmdlets if you want them private then ? make a private / internal class that doesnt inherit PSCmdlet then

@SantiagoSquarzon, it appears that the OP -does- want to be able to invoke the code IFF an environment variable is set.

Can you just add some validation code to the start of your “conditionally available” cmdlets that checks the environment variable value before it runs the main body - that could throw a meaningful exception if the value isn’t what you expect, and would involve less headscratching about why the cmdlets are “visible” on some machines but not others for no obvious reason :-)…

If you quietly update your question without engaging with prior commenters / answers, your update is likely to go unnoticed. There is a mechanism that allows you to run code in your DLL on import - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624757/45375 - but I'm not aware of any ability to control what gets exported that way.


I can't think of an environment variable-based solution, but if executing a command to make the "hidden" cmdlets visible is acceptable, you can take the following approach:

Create a full-fledged, directory-based module around your cmdlet-containing *.dll, through whose module manifest (.psd1) you can limit what cmdlets are made available to the caller on import.

If you want to (later or alternatively) load all cmdlets, run Import-Module -Force directly on the *.dll, which will import all cmdlets (all public Cmdlet and/or PSCmdlet-derived classes).



If you define helper function Import-AllCmdlets (source code below), you can force importing of all cmdlets as follows, assuming your module's name is Foo:
# -Verbose shows what cmdlets are imported.
Get-Module -ListAvailable Foo | Import-AllCmdlets -Verbose

Import-AllCmdlets source code:
function Import-AllCmdlets {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [psmoduleinfo] $module
  )
  process {
    if ($module.RootModule -notlike '*.dll') {
      Write-Error "Module $module has no binary root module."
      return
    }
    Import-Module -Force (Join-Path (Split-Path $module.Path) $module.RootModule)
  }
}

